# In PL/SQL function I am getting error "Only a function is allowed here". How can i resolve it?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

[this is the error
 i am getting  while running  the code although. it does not show error in code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGoUj.png)

I want to create a function in which I have to display the total balance in words.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spell_number (p_number IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   TYPE my Array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (255);

   l_str myArray
         := myArray ('',
                     ' thousand ',
                     ' million ',
                     ' billion ',
                     ' trillion ',
                     ' quadrillion ',
                     ' quintillion ',
                     ' sextillion ',
                     ' septillion ',
                     ' octillion ',
                     ' nonillion ',
                     ' decillion ',
                     ' undecillion ',
                     ' duodecillion ');

   l_num      VARCHAR2 (50) DEFAULT TRUNC (p_number);
   l_return   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. l_str.COUNT
   LOOP
      EXIT WHEN l_num IS NULL;

      IF (SUBSTR (l_num, LENGTH (l_num) - 2, 3) <> 0)
      THEN
         l_return :=
            TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (SUBSTR (l_num, LENGTH (l_num) - 2, 3), 'J'),
                     'Jsp')
            || l_str (i)
            || l_return;
      END IF;

      l_num := SUBSTR (l_num, 1, LENGTH (l_num) - 3);
   END LOOP;

   RETURN l_return;
END;
```

Comment: The function itself is OK, it works (at least, `select spell_number(100) from dual;` returns `One Hundred`) so you're having problems elsewhere. Where exactly, we know not, but might if you decide to tell us.

Comment: ok let me add screen shot

Comment: You appear to be trying to create a DB function in a panel that's asking you to enter a formula.. I think, I'm not familiar with Reports. Seems like the wrong tool though, or at least the wrong part of the tool. (Or, from a quick search, do you just need to remove the 'create or replace' part?)

Comment: i need to create function

Answer (score 2):

Ah, that's Reports Builder.

Remove `CREATE OR REPLACE` and it should be just fine.